Fixed field of involutions in simple algebras
Let $(K,\bar{})$ be a field with a nontrivial involution whose fixed field is $K_0$. Does there exist a finite-dimensional simple $(K,\bar{})$-algebra $(A,*)$ with involution $*$ which is not central over $K$?
Would you give me an example?
The simple $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with conjugate transpose would be considered that example if I did not want the involution to be nontrivial. However, I want the field $K$ to have nontrivial involution which is compatible with $*$, i.e. $(k\cdot1_A)^*=\bar{k}\cdot 1_A$.

I'm confused—you say that $\bar\cdot$ is nontrivial, so the containment $K_0 \subseteq K$ is proper.  Then you say that $A$ is not central over $K$, so the containment $K \subseteq Z(A)$ is proper.  That is, the desired conclusion seems to follow from your hypotheses.  So are you really asking whether the hypotheses can be realised?

You are absolutely right to be confused. Yes, indeed, I am wondering whether we have such an algebra or not. I am going to edit the question properly.

Unless I am misunderstanding, an easy modification of your example does it.  Let $\overline\cdot$ be the Galois conjugation of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)/\mathbb Q(\sqrt3)$, but don't take $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$.  Instead, take $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$, with the restriction of $\overline\cdot$, and let $A = \operatorname{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3))$, with $a^* = \overline{a^{\mathsf T}}$ for $a \in A$.

Would you tell me what the Galois conjugation of $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$$ is? and what is $K_0$ here?

Re, there's only one conjugation, namely, $a + b\sqrt2 \mapsto a - b\sqrt2$ for every $a, b \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$; and $K_0$ is the fixed field of that conjugation on $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$, which is just $\mathbb Q$.
